# Why am I getting E2531 "Method requires explicit type argument"

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-10-seattle

The code below relies pretty heavily on generics, and I think exposes a bug in the generics handling. But maybe there is simply something I don't understand.

The compiler raises the error:

```
E2531 Method 'CreateBaseItem' requires explicit type arguments
```

on the line:

```
foo3 := TFactory.CreateBaseItem<TDescendentFunctionsGroup2.Select>;
```

yet as far as I can tell, instantiating `foo1` through `foo4` should all be essentially identical. This complete program highlights the issue:

```
program SO53568763;

type
  TBaseItem = class(TInterfacedObject);

  IListableItem<T> = interface
    ['{6FD07ACB-04BB-4BFC-A38C-9B98F86DBC25}']
  end;

  TSomeDescendent = class(TBaseItem, IListableItem<TSomeDescendent>)
  end;

  TSelectFunctionsGenerator<T: TBaseItem, IListableItem<T>> = class(TBaseItem)
  end;

  TFunctionsGroup<T: TBaseItem, IListableItem<T>> = class
  public
    type
      Select = TSelectFunctionsGenerator<T>;
  end;

  TDescendentFunctionsGroup1 = class(TFunctionsGroup<TSomeDescendent>);
  TDescendentFunctionsGroup2 = TFunctionsGroup<TSomeDescendent>;

  TFactory = class
  public
    class function CreateBaseItem<T: TBaseItem>: T;
  end;

class function TFactory.CreateBaseItem<T>;
begin
end;

procedure Foo;
var
  foo: TSelectFunctionsGenerator<TSomeDescendent>;
  foo1: TFunctionsGroup<TSomeDescendent>.Select;
  foo2: TDescendentFunctionsGroup1.Select;
  foo3: TDescendentFunctionsGroup2.Select;
begin
  foo := TFactory.CreateBaseItem<TSelectFunctionsGenerator<TSomeDescendent>>;
  foo1 := TFactory.CreateBaseItem<TFunctionsGroup<TSomeDescendent>.Select>;
  foo2 := TFactory.CreateBaseItem<TDescendentFunctionsGroup1.Select>;
  foo3 := TFactory.CreateBaseItem<TDescendentFunctionsGroup2.Select>;
end;

begin
end.
```

It is strange that `TDescendentFunctionsGroup2.Select` is explicit enough to declare a variable of that type, but not explicit enough to use as the generic argument to `CreateBaseItem`.

Comment: I suppose it comes from other parts of unit/project. Tried to compile your code - all compiles ok - https://gist.github.com/lynxnake/e49072f7871314567fe97c005eeed999

Comment: @SerhiiKheilyk The code above was from a completely new delphi project that I created to demonstrate the problem. There is nothing in it aside from what I posted above. Which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: Tokyo, Delphi 10.2 update 3, version info - 25.0.31059.3231

Comment: Btw, I am pretty sure there should be at least form class declaration and interface uses list above your code. Otherwise compilation error would be about these parts missing.
I would at least give the snippet I posted some try

Comment: Note that I simplified your code by removing visual components, and making it a complete program.

Comment: FWIW, this compiles fine in 10.1 Berlin too. Build 24.0.25048.9432. But it fails in Seattle.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thank you for cleaning up the code. I hope the fix stays in Delphi Rio as we are planning on upgrading shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does appear to be a compiler bug. The difference between `TDescendentFunctionsGroup1` and `TDescendentFunctionsGroup2` is that the former is a new class derived from `TFunctionsGroup<TSomeDescendent>` and the latter is an alias to `TFunctionsGroup<TSomeDescendent>`.

So my guess is that the parser or compiler has an issue with aliases to generic types.

I'm really not sure what benefit the alias gives you, in any case, so I'd simply write it like this:

```
var
  foo3: TFunctionsGroup<TSomeDescendent>.Select;
...
foo3 := TFactory.CreateBaseItem<TFunctionsGroup<TSomeDescendent>.Select>;
```

Comment: The point of this all was that inside TFunctionsGroup<T> I made 20 other generic functions. So all I have to do is something like TMyAlias=class(TFunctionsGroup<TSomeClass)), then elsewhere in the program I can do somevar:=TMyAlias.Select, someOtherVar:=TMyAlias.OtherFunc1, i.e. it is simply designed to do less typing so I dont always have to write TFunctionsGroup<TMyType>.Select, instead TMyTypeFuncs.Select. If TMyType is a long name, it just saves a bit of typing.